# Comparison between three members of an object

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop, object

Consider objects of the following type:

```
public class MyObject
{
    // "defining" attributes
    private string member1;
    private string member2;
    private string member3;

    // other attributes
    private string member4;
    private string member5;

    // ctor
    public MyObject(){}

    public bool compare(MyObject that)
    {
       // compare this object with another (that)
    }
```

The `compare()` method should behave as follows. **It only considers "defining" attributes.** If they are **all** different between two objects, it should return false. If they are **all** the same, return false. In other cases, return true (if only one or two of them differ between the two objects).

The question is, do I have to resort to a huge `if` statement for this? Is there a "better" solution?

Comment: Can you created `definingString` as `List<string>` instead of n string variables.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I don't see why not. I still don't see how it could make the comparison easier, though. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I have received multiple answers to the question, but I am yet to try them out. I will do so tomorrow.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues in it.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer, it looks like it will solve my problem, but I will update you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating `n` number of strings, you can create property called `List<string> DefiningAttributes` and `List<string> OtherAttributes`.

Now add values to this lists where you want, for now I am doing it in constructor. Use `Except()` method to get difference from `DefiningAttributes` and `OtherAttributes`

Check below implementation

```
public class MyObject
{
    // "defining" attributes
    public List<string> DefiningAttributes { get; set; }

    // other attributes
    public List<string> OtherAttributes { get; set; }

    public MyObject()
    {
        //I used constructor to assign values
        DefiningAttributes = new List<string>() { "ABC",  "PQR",  "XYZ" };
        OtherAttributes = new List<string>() { "ABC",  "PQR",  "Stackoverflow" };
    }

    public bool compare(MyObject that)
    {
         var difference = this.DefiningAttributes.Except(that.DefiningAttributes);
         //Return false If they are all different between two objects OR if they are all same
         if(difference.Count() == this.DefiningAttributes.Count() || !difference.Any())
                return false;

          //Otherwise return true
          return true;
    }
}
```

---

For more details, read [Enumerable.Except method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it

```
var comp1 = this.member1 == that.member1;
var comp2 = this.member2 == that.member2;
var comp3 = this.member3 == that.member3;

var comparisons = new List<string>() { comp2, comp3 };

return comparisons.Any(val => val != comp1 );
```

`comp1`, `comp2` and `comp3` will be bools. If any of those comparisons are not the same as the first comparison*, we know we have different results.

[*] You could use any reference point instead of the first comparison

**Edit:** Whoops, I thought this was a javascript question, but I then realized it was C#. I just changed my answer to use C# syntax, but the idea is the same. This requires the Linq extension method `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick.
If you want to increase the number of defining properties you just edit the size of the array or swap it to a list.

It should iterate over them and when one does not mach return true.
If at the end none matches returns false.

```
public class MyObject
{

    // "defining" attributes
    public string[] definingAttributes = new string[3];

    // other attributes
    private string member4;
    private string member5;

    // ctor
    public MyObject() { }

    public bool compare(MyObject that)
    {
        bool? previousResult = null;
        // compare this object with another (that)
        for (int i = 0; i < definingAttributes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (previousResult == null)
            {
                previousResult = definingAttributes[i] == that.definingAttributes[i];
            }
            if (definingAttributes[i] != that.definingAttributes[i])
            {
                if (previousResult != (definingAttributes[i] == that.definingAttributes[i]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```